# Expected value of the number of set of nested substes

Tags: probability, statistics, expectation

Suppose there is a set $S_1= \{c_1,c_2,...,c_n \}$, we create subset $S_{i+1} \subseteq S_i$ as follow:

$\forall c_j \in S_i;1 \leq j \leq n $ we toss a coin, if it is head we pick $c_j$ to be inserted in $S_{i+1}$ else it will not.

We repeat this until we reach to $S_h \ne \phi $ and $S_{h+1} = \phi$ (infact this data structure is a skip list). The expected value of $h$ which is number of $S_i$s (its height) equals to $\log n$, $$PR(height = h) = n/2^h $$ if $$n/2^h = 1 \rightarrow 2^h = n \rightarrow h = \log n$$

[image]

Now it has been claimed that

> There is a positive constant $c$ such that for all sufficiently large real numbers $s$, we have $$PR(h\geq s \log n) \leq 1/n^{cs}$$

I really have no idea how to prove it (**may be Chernoff bound is needed!**)

Comment: Some things seem off here. If $X$ denotes the height, and $P(X=h) = n2^{-h}$ for $h\in\mathbb{N}$, then $\sum_{h=1}^{\infty}P(X=h) = n$, which isn't necessarily equal to one.

Comment: why you didn't limit the $h$?

Comment: How do you mean limit $h$? What I mean is that if you sum the probabilities of a (discrete) random variable over all its possible values you should end up with $1$, which is not the case here.

Comment: @Marc please look at this page http://www.mathcs.emory.edu/~cheung/Courses/323/Syllabus/Map/skip-list-perf.html I took the idea from this

Comment: I'm not sure what the intended algorithm is supposed to do. However, if the towers behave as in your question here is what goes wrong. The height of the skip list is the height of the highest tower. Therefore P(skiplist has height $h$) = P(Some tower has height $h$ and all the others have height $\le h$). This is definitely something else than the probabilty that some tower has height $h$, since we want the highest tower to have height $h$.